# Onclick of link does not work after changing href, but open in new tab works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below anchor tag. I'm trying to search for the attribute that has value xyz and then changing its herf and also removing the unwanted attributes.

After executing this on the console, I can see the href is changed but clicking on the link does not work. However when I open in a new tab it opens with the new href

```
<a data-data="test" data-name="xyz" href="#" class="button">this is a link</a>

var pmLink = document.querySelectorAll("[data-name='xyz']");

if (pmLink) {
    pmLink[0].href = "http://www.google.com";
    pmLink[0].removeAttribute("data-data");
    pmLink[0].removeAttribute("data-name");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? It doesn't go to http://www.google.com?

Comment: @Toxnyc Yes, It doesn't go to google.com

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I don't see any.

Answer (score 0):

Change to: `var pmLink = document.querySelector("[data-name='xyz']");`

Working snippet:

```js
var pmLink = document.querySelector("[data-name='xyz']");
if (pmLink) {
    pmLink.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com');
    pmLink.removeAttribute("data-data");
    pmLink.removeAttribute("data-name");
}
```

```html
<a data-data="test" data-name="xyz" href="#" class="button">this is a link</a>
```

If you have more then one `data-name="xyz"` then use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then you need to [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and "[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)".

Hope that helps! Enjoy Code!

Comment: Still does not help. The behavior is the same.
is it possible to add a onclick function instead?

Comment: What do you mean? You can check the inspector to see that both data attribute has been removed and the href set to google.com

Comment: yes everything in inspect element looks fine, but for some reason it does not open google.com :( . is there a alternate way to achieve this sam behaviour?